# table and generator in the range from to

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to generate the range of numbers that I generate and in the table start from the given number to the given number. the point is that there would be some two inputs that will ask from some numbers to start and where to end and that the tables should also adapt to this or how will it be from 1 to 53 then 53 table cells will be displayed. can anyone do this?

```
$(function () {
    var bingo = {
      selectedNumbers: [],
      generateRandom: function () {
        var min = 1;
        var max = 89;
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        return random;
      },
      generateNextRandom: function () {
        if (bingo.selectedNumbers.length > 88) {
          alert("Koniec");
          return 0;
        }
        var random = bingo.generateRandom();
        while ($.inArray(random, bingo.selectedNumbers) > -1) {
          random = bingo.generateRandom();
        }
        bingo.selectedNumbers.push(random);
        return random;
      },
    };
    $("td").each(function () {
      var concatClass = this.cellIndex + "" + this.parentNode.rowIndex;
      var numberString = parseInt(concatClass, 10).toString();
      $(this)
        .addClass("cell" + numberString)
        .text(numberString);
      $(".cell" + numberString).attr("CellValue", numberString);
    });
    $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
      var random = bingo.generateNextRandom().toString();
      $(".bigNumberDisplay span").text(random);
      $("td.cell" + random).addClass("selected");
      $("td").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("CellValue") === random) {
          $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
        }
      });
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var returnString = "Are you sure?";
      if (e) {
        e.returnValue = returnString;
      }
      return returnString;
    };
  });
```

```
<head>
  <title> Bingo</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>

  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bigNumberDisplay">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="btnGenerate" type="button" value="Wylosuj numer stolika" />
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div class="numbersTable">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <br/>

  </div>
</body>

</body>

</html>
```

```
div {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .bigNumberDisplay {
    font-size: 6em;
  }

  .numbersTable {
    font-size: 1.6em;
  }

  table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  table,tr,td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: solid 1px #999;
  }

  td {
    min-width: 100px;
    color: #fff;
  }

  td.selected {
    color: #000000;
  }
```

Comment: Is the above code pasted not working ? or what specific is the issue? Can you mention that ?

Comment: there is no problem, the code works only I would like to set a limit of numbers e.g. from 1 to 50 and that the generator would generate numbers only from 1 to 50 and the table was only from 1 to 50. and I do not want to change the code only on the page there were two questions from how many to how many numbers have it be

Comment: @KubaPiłat How should the User enter these two values?

Comment: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)) % 50
This will generate random number between 0 to 50 only.

Comment: Yes, also how would someone enter those values ?

Comment: ohhh you want to generate the table with empty cells ?

Comment: on the main page there should be two queries, the first is to be the number from which the table and number should be generated, and the second question is to what number the table and number should be generated

Comment: so if the user wants to generate numbers from 1 to 20 then 20 empty tables are to be shown on the page

Comment: I have 90 empty tables drawn by default and I want to do so that if the user only wants 20 tables, 20 tables are to be shown to him

Comment: @KubaPiłat this creates more questions than it answers. Do you want the additional cells removed or hidden? Show the number of columns change? What if the number of cells is not Even, like if it's 23 cells in the table? You need to clarify the issue further and what you want to have done.

Comment: they can hide or delete in total as you feel better and easier it is indifferent. If it is odd, like 23, it will be 2 columns of 10 rows and these three will stick out.

Comment: seriously how better and easier you are because it is only to pass it does not have to be a professional project

Comment: it will be a simple project as easier

Comment: please help me. it doesn't have to be a complicated, simple, simple project

Answer (score 0):

You can store `min` and `max` in the Object. Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var bingo = {
    selectedNumbers: [],
    min: 1,
    max: 50,
    generateRandom: function() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (bingo.max - bingo.min + 1)) + bingo.min;
    },
    generateNextRandom: function() {
      if (bingo.selectedNumbers.length > 88) {
        alert("Koniec");
        return 0;
      }
      var random = bingo.generateRandom();
      while ($.inArray(random, bingo.selectedNumbers) > -1) {
        random = bingo.generateRandom();
      }
      bingo.selectedNumbers.push(random);
      return random;
    },
  };
  $("td").each(function() {
    var concatClass = this.cellIndex + "" + this.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var numberString = parseInt(concatClass, 10).toString();
    $(this)
      .addClass("cell" + numberString)
      .text(numberString);
    $(".cell" + numberString).attr("CellValue", numberString);
  });
  $("#btnGenerate").click(function() {
    var random = bingo.generateNextRandom().toString();
    $(".bigNumberDisplay span").text(random);
    $("td.cell" + random).addClass("selected");
    $("td").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("CellValue") === random) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
      }
    });
  });
  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var returnString = "Are you sure?";
    if (e) {
      e.returnValue = returnString;
    }
    return returnString;
  };
});
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

.bigNumberDisplay {
  font-size: 6em;
}

.numbersTable {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #999;
}

td {
  min-width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}

td.selected {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bigNumberDisplay">
    <span>0</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="btnGenerate" type="button" value="Wylosuj numer stolika" />
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="numbersTable">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br/>
</div>
```

You can then change that in Initialization or you can add a Setter function so you can these them from User User Input.

You can also use this to check / curb your cell count.

Comment: You could do it because I embrace JS on average and this project is for an additional grade at school